# How to join an array with nil entries i.e. ["a", nil, "b"] treating nil as whitespace

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this

```
array = ["a", nil, "b"]
```

and when I run `join` on it like this

```
result = array.join
```

and `puts` the `result`, I get "ab", not "a b".

Help!

EDIT please understanding this in the context of my actual code:

```
def caesar_cipher(initial_string, shift_number)
    letter_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    modified_initial_string = initial_string.split("")
    modified_initial_string.map! { |letter|
        letter.downcase!
        if letter_list.include?(letter)
            letter = letter_list[letter_list.index(letter) - shift_number]
        end
    }
    result = modified_initial_string.join
    puts modified_initial_string
    puts result
end
caesar_cipher("Hello this", 1)
```

My result in the terminal is :

```
g
d
k
k
n

s
g
h
r
gdkknsghr
```

Comment: @jonathan-lonowski I'm aware, and that was intentional ... I didn't want anything to happen to the whitespaces in the `map` action. I wanted the whitespaces should emerge unchanged. I was successful, as can be observed from the result of `print modified_initial_string`

Comment: Your statement is wrong. `["a", " ", "b"].join` does not return `"ab"`, it returns `"a b"`.

Comment: @sawa - it does return "ab" in the context of the the rest of my code (which you can see in my question)

Comment: I don't see `["a", " ", "b"]` nor `array` in the rest of your question. And whatever the context is, `["a", " ", "b"].join` does not return `"ab"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) works as expected:

```
>> array = ["a", " ", "b"]
=> ["a", " ", "b"]
>> array.join
=> "a b"
>> puts array.join
a b
```

---

**UPDATE: Complete Code**

You did not consider `else` case.

```
def caesar_cipher(initial_string, shift_number)
    letter_list = (?a..?z).to_a

    initial_string.each_char.map { |letter|
        letter.downcase!
        if letter_list.include?(letter)
            letter_list[letter_list.index(letter) - shift_number]
        else
            letter
        end
    }.join
end

puts caesar_cipher("Hello this", 1)
```

Comment: thanks. do you mind taking a look at the question? I've added some context.

Comment: @macsplean, Remove `puts modified_initial_string` line.  Replace `puts result` with `result`.  Then, replace `caesar_cipher("Hello this", 1)` with `puts caesar_cipher("Hello this", 1)`.

Comment: @macsplean, `puts` with array object prints items with newlines (for every items).

Comment: thanks, that code is certainly cleaner, but the result is still the unwanted gdkknsghr. I want gdkkn sghr

Comment: @macsplean, I added an complete code. You did not consider `else` case.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's not a `" "` in `modified_initial_string`.

```
puts modified_initial_string.inspect
# ["g", "d", "k", "k", "n", nil, "s", "g", "h", "r"]
#                           ^^^
```

And `.join` will remove `nil`s from the `result`.

The `nil` comes from spaces not being included in `letter_list`, so they fail the `if`. So, if you want to keep them, you'll want to add an alternate condition for them:

```
if letter_list.include?(letter)
    # ...
elsif letter == " "
   letter
end
```

Comment: @jonathan-lonoski thank you. do you have any advice as to how I should split up the initial string to get a result with a whitespace instead of a `nil`?

Comment: @macsplean Added a 2nd snippet which should help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer has already been answered, the best would have been to join the array with `.join(' ')` in the end.

I would suggest you to add some Ruby flavor in this as:

```
def caesar_cipher(initial_string, shift_number)
  initial_string.split.map do |x|
    x.each_char.map { |y| (y.ord - shift_number).chr }.join
    #above shifts in ascii for you
  end.join(' ')
end

caesar_cipher("Hello World", 1)
=> "Gdkkn Vnqkc"
```

`#ord` gives you the ascii of a character, whereas `#chr` converts back an integer to it's ascii character equivalent.

Also, in your code, it's better to replace:

```
letter_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

with:

```
letter_list = ('a'..'z').to_a
```

**Ruby FTW!**